# Почему говорят "вострить лыжи"? Why the "skis" are being "sharpened"?

Tags: этимология

Впервые я встретил это выражение в сказке Шарля Перро "Синяя Борода":

> Он узнал братьев своей жены - один служил в драгунах, другой в конных егерях, - и тотчас навострил лыжи; но братья нагнали его, прежде чем он успел забежать за крыльцо.

Тогда это выражение показалось мне каким-то чуждым: дело происходит в доме, ни о каком снеге в сказке не упоминалось, да и деревянные лыжи не очень-то заостришь. Я подумал что это калька с французского. Но оказывается, что это выражение достаточно распространено и упоминается во многих фразеологических и толковых словарях.

Сейчас смысл выражения мне понятен - в словаре Ожегова, например, написано:

> (разг.) приготовиться бежать, а также убежать.

Но почему "вострить"? Во всех примерах употребления слова "вострить" = "острить" лыжи упоминаются только в составе фразеологизма. Остальные же значения:

1. ОСТРИТЬ, -рю, -ришь; нсв. что. Нар.-разг.

   1. Делать острым; заострять. О. меч. О. топор. Кот острит когти.
   2. Делать более восприимчивым. О. память. О. слух. * Нужда ум острит (Погов.).
2. ОСТРИТЬ, -рю, -ришь; нсв. Говорить остроты; шутить. Удачно, постоянно о. Любит о. кто-л.

Почему же острят, вострят лыжи? Их действительно острят (делают более острыми) или имеется в виду некое переносное значение как в выражении "навострил уши"?

---

The literal meaning of "вострить лыжи" is "sharpen the skis". Though in all the dictionaries I have seen the word "острить" is never applied to skis.

Is the usage of the word "вострить" here metaphorical, or skis can be sharpened?

Comment: In Polish, *łyżwy* means "skates".

Comment: А почему вы не рассматриваете такой вариант, что это именно и есть "острить" в буквальном смысле этого слова? Перед выходом из дому подточить, подправить острые передние концы лыж, чтобы они лучше снег рассекали > собраться уходить; уйти. Сейчас их не острят, но и технологии изготовления лыж серьёзно изменились.

Comment: @YellowSky Я не знаю принципов ухода за лыжами, поэтому и вопрос. А острые концы лыж - не такие уж и острые. На фото по ссылке - охотничьи лыжи http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%B8. Носы у лыж скорее закругленные чем острые. Не встречал в интернете подтверждения о том что лыжи раньше острили. У современных горных лыж есть металлические кромки, которые острят, но это недавнее конструктивное изменение.

Comment: @Quassnoi This can explain why "вострить": wyostrzyć łyżwy = "точить коньки" (at least by Google Translate suggestions). But is it borrowed from Polish?

Comment: @YellowSky Википедия: "лыжи использовались для передвижения по глубокому снегу в лесу во время охоты, военных действий в зимних условиях и т. п. Они были короткие (150 см в среднем) и широкие (15-20 см), удобные скорее для переступания, чем для скольжения. Иногда лыжи подбивались камусом (шкурой с ноги оленя), чтобы облегчить передвижение вверх по склону". Т.е. лыжи - это не очень скоростное передвижение. Бегать на лыжах начали в конце 19 в. А Национальный корпус находит упоминание "навострить лыжи" в 1800 году.

Comment: @Artemix: *wyostrzyć* is perfective (*наточить* in Russian). I don't know whether it is borrowed from Polish or not, that's why it's a comment, but the usage of *острить* instead of *точить* and the prosthetic *в* suggest Western influence indeed.

Comment: @Quassnoi - В русском много других выражений в протетическим в-, напр. "востроглазый", "навострить уши".

Comment: @YellowSky: yes, that's why I wrote "suggest".

Comment: Могу предложить другой вариант: "навострил лыжи" значит "направил острия (концы) лыж в определённую сторону, т. е. ушёл." Типа как говорят "направил стопы", хоть мы и не показываем ступнёй направление.

Comment: @YellowSky: "Навострить уши" - обычно говорится о животных, например о собаках. У многих собак уши имеют заострённую форму, и, когда они прислушиваются, уши у них стоят торчком и направлены в одну сторону. По моему, достаточно много общего с готовыми к бегу лыжами. В корпусе уши и лыжи начинают вострить примерно в одно и то же время: 1830-е годы, так что сложно сказать, что что-то появилось первым

Comment: One says "sharpen skis" in English too. That's the standard term for having your edges sharpened.

Comment: @SAH This is true for modern alpine skis, but in 1800 when the saying already existed it wasn't so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Покопавшись в Национальном корпусе нашел множество примеров использования слов "вострить" и "навострить", которые не приводятся в словарях. Некоторые из этих примеров существуют в единичном случае, некоторые (навострить глаза) встречались когда-то достаточно часто.

- В буквальном смысле (наточить): вострить/навострить можно ножи, топоры, пики, штыки, мечи, зубные инструменты (стоматолога);
- В переносном смысле - готовиться к нападению: вострить когти правосудия, вострить зубы на кого-то или что-то, вострить кулаки:

  > Он только и знает, что кулаки вострит на меня, да так на меня поглядывает, как словно ты на батраков, когда их таскать захочешь. [П. А. Плавильщиков. Бобыль (1790)]
- Поднять торчком: навострить уши (о животных) и даже палец:

  > ― Вот, ― Петр Семенович многозначительно навострил палец, ― вот речь закоренелого представителя эпохи Кали-Юги! [Михаил Елизаров. Pasternak (2003)]
- Внимательно слушать/смотреть/чувствовать: навострить уши, глаза, сердце; навострить слух, зрение; навостренный взгляд. Даже человек в целом может быть навостренным:

  > Дворовые, как люди более или менее навостренные, с вежливостью раскланивались с немкой и старались заискать в ее расположении. [Г.И. Успенский. Тише воды, ниже травы / Из цикла «Разоренье» (1870)]
  >   Пойми ты: навострил он меня настолько, что поняла я, отчего он стал пить. [А. И. Левитов. Погибшее, но милое создание (1862)]
- упражняться в разговорах - навострить язык:

  > А так как история моей женитьбы, мое бегство и болезнь не могли не навострить языков, то это меня раздражало. [П. И. Чайковский. Переписка с Н.Ф. фон-Мекк (1877)]
  >
  > Книжек начиталась, со студентами язык навострила, социалистку из себя кривляешь, ― берегись! [А. В. Амфитеатров. Марья Лусьева (1903)]
- Ну и заключительный, самый общий смысл - подготовить:

  > навостренную шуточку за пазухой приберегал
  >   навострив свои бандуры, грянули «Интернационал»
  >   начав со всхлипа, словно доскребаясь до нужного голоса, и, достав, навострив его, пустил тонкий и длинный, режущий по живому, жалобный и убийственный стон.
  >   навострила карандаш (приготовилась писать)
  >   навострив в бумагу карандаш (направив)
  >   с вечера навострили там сундук
  >   навострили перья и штыки

Встретилось несколько вариаций на тему "собираться уходить":

> Хоть и навострил крылья в сторону, а чую, на мое гнездо вернется… [В. Я. Шишков. Угрюм-река. Ч. 1-4 (1913-1932)]
>
> ...доказал отцам города, что просто обязан попасть в состав делегации чиновников, навостривших стопы в Швецию... [Несколько шагов от иглы до Воли (2003) // «Сельская новь», 2003.12.16]

Так что "навострить" в сочетании "навострить лыжи" скорее всего означает просто - подготовить к использованию. Что касается их парности и остроты носов - подавляющая часть примеров позволяет вострить что угодно вне зависимости от остроты и парности предметов.

---

Looks like in old times (19 century) the word "вострить", "навострить" was used very often because there were a lot of weapons or other tools (e.g. for writing) that required sharpening before usage and so the word itself had in some phrases the meaning "prepare something to be used" (examples include fists, tongue, musical instrument, joke, trunk), so "sharpening the skis" was in fact just "preparing the skis" and not real "sharpening".

Answer (score 1):

**Навострить лыжи**

**Смысл выражения:** собирать уйти куда-нибудь, либо удалиться откуда-нибудь.

**Возникновение фразы:** каждый, кто хоть раз в жизни видел лыжи, наверняка помнит, что концы лыж заострены - это сделано для того, чтобы лыжи лучше рассекали снег и, следовательно, лучше скользили. В старину, когда массового производства лыж специализированными фирмами не было и в помине, люди изготавливали лыжи самостоятельно, и, разумеется, острили их концы.
Конечно же, перед тем как выйти на лыжную прогулку сначала нужно было наострить лыжи, иначе на них никуда не уедешь. Со временем словосочетание "острить лыжи", имеющее вполне практический смысл, преобразовалось в словосочетание "навострить лыжи", имеющее смысл переносный, и к самим лыжам вообще не имеющий никакого отношения.

*источник*: http://yznai-ka.ru/publ/quot_n_quot/navostrit_lyzhi/13-1-0-1692

Comment: Вот это вот "наострить лыжи перед прогулкой" мне как-то не внушает доверия. Жаль что на сайте не указан автор этого толкования.

Comment: Как лыжник-любитель с 20-летним стажем могу сказать, что объяснение крайне сомнительное (да что уж там говорить - бредовое). Острота концу лыж (беговых) и даром не нужна. Главное, чтобы передняя часть вверх загибалась - это нужно, чтобы наезжать на непримятый снег впереди. А какой остроты конец - дело десятое.

Answer (score 0):

"Вострить лыжи", как это не смешно, но идея с "заточить носы (острия) лыж" весьма распространена даже в России. Сам по себе, в отрыве от фразеологизма - факт имел место быть. Но на самом деле все намного проще. 
Лыжи, для улучшения скольжения и ходкости необходимо СМАЗЫВАТЬ. Раньше это был жир (животный жир, по типу гусиного жира). РАНЬШЕ большинство лыж снизу обтягивались мехом, который повышал ходовые характеристики, но слипался от растаявшего и вновь замерзшего снега. Если же смазать мех жиром - он перестанет принимать влагу и смерзаться, образовывать ледяные наросты. А значит - лыжи будут лучше идти и РАЗРЕЗАТЬ снег. Лыжи помогают идти по снегу -> помогают РАЗРЕЗАТЬ снег -> лыжи РЕЖУТ снег -> если их смазать то они будут лучше РЕЗАТЬ снег -> лыжи ОСТРЯТ (устаревшая форма - ВОСТРЯТ) с помощью ЖИРА (лыжной смазки) -> Подготовить (смазать) лыжи означает ЗАТОЧИТЬ("сделать острее", острить, вострить).
И никаких острых концов (которые делали СРАЗУ и ОДИН раз при изготовлении), ибо мне сложно представить лыжи в роли карандаша :)

Comment: Смазать лыжи = заточить лыжи - есть какое-нибудь подтверждение этому? Если бы дело было именно в смазке - есть выражение "на мази", которое употребляется как минимум с 1835 года: "И потому доставил ему завидный пост, приближавший его к герцогу; место кабинет-секретаря было у племянничка на мази. [И. И. Лажечников. Ледяной дом (1835)]". Мне кажется что найденное мною выражение "навострить сундук" показывает что вострить можно (было) даже предметы неспособные быть острыми.

Comment: Другими словами "вострить" как "подготовить" мне кажется более логичным объяснением чем переносное значение "наострить для резки снега" = "смазать чтобы лыжи лучше шли".

Comment: Смазать лыжи = подготовить лыжи = заострить лыжи. Выражения рассекать (снег, лед, воду) на слуху и используются постоянно. Корабли и серферы - рассекают волны, фигуристы и бегуны на коньках - рассекают лед. Лыжники - рассекают снег (особенно если речь идет об охотниках). Так было и сто и двести лет назад и пятьсот (за исключением коньков и серферов, хотя вроде коньки уже были в Голландии).

Comment: Далее - вы передергиваете, аки старый софист. Термин ВОСТРИТЬ(позднее - острить) тянется со времен когда даже прадедушка Красного Солнышка даже в планах не значился. Вострить уже тогда означало ГОТОВИТЬ что-либо к чему-либо. А смазка шкуры на лыжах жиром ... ВАМ не кажется что это иначе как "ПОДГОТОВКОЙ" лыж к охоте/походу назвать сложно, а?

Иными словами главную мысль ВОСТРИТЬ = ПОДГОТОВИТЬ ВЫ поняли верно. На будущее сделаю пометку - метать "факты" и "аллюзии" не стоит, ибо пропускают... Буду проще. Но уровня "Семки есть" - не обещаю. Туповат вельми. Извините уж...

Comment: Вопрос был поставлен так: лыжи в буквальном смысле острили, или это переносное значение? Насколько я понимаю ваш ответ - лыжи "острили" смазывая их жиром, т.е. "острить" здесь использовано в переносном смысле.

Comment: Да. Если откинуть аллюзии и пояснения. вострить=подготавливать=смазывать=переносное значение.

Answer (score 0):

Доброго времени суток.
Моё мнение по поводу выражения "Точить лыжи", это означало сделать(вырезать) лыжи.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос был про "вострить лыжи". Цепочка синонимов вострить-острить-точить-вырезать достаточно длинная, есть и более "близкие" объяснения этого выражения.

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение, что это выражение: "Вострить лыжи" каким-то образом пришло из польского языка, в котором лыжвы это коньки, а вострить это точить. Тогда все становится на свои места. Коньки необходимо затачивать периодически.

Comment: this hypothesis was given by the OP himself back in 2013 in the comments under the OP  https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/2722/Почему-говорят-вострить-лыжи-why-the-skis-are-being-sharpened/17891#comment8830_2722